# NHibernate using single configuration file to connect to multiple dbs

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, session, configuration

I'd like to have a single configuration file and then when I'm creating a session change the hibernate-configuration->session-factory->connection.connection_string property to what I want it to be programmatically? Is it possible?

UPDATE:

I believe I may be able to do this like this

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);

cfg.Properties["connection.connection_string"] = ...
```

What I would wonder than, if that is ok, Is this a bad way to handle connecting to a different database for each session? if so why etc. I'd also like to know if/how you can open an nhibernate session with a .net connection object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ISessionFactory.OpenSession()` overload that takes a `IDbConnection`](http://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISessionFactory.cs?r=3565#l39).

That's how [Castle's `DifferentDatabaseScope`](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/ActiveRecord/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Scopes/DifferentDatabaseScope.cs) does it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use different configuration files per each data base just becouse you will be able to switch dialects very esasy.

Comment: Thats the way I would like to do it but because we have a different DAL for a seperate part of the project we want to be able to read the connection from the same place. Its office politics **** . I've found also I can use a single config file and open a session with a standard sql connection.Again I'm worried slightly about performance implications?

Answer (score 0):

You may also see this answer as it allows full configuration of session factories through one file. [Configure NHibernate hibernate.cfg.xml file to have more connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450300/configure-nhibernate-hibernate-cfg-xml-file-to-have-more-connection-strings/10645667#10645667)