# Can one configure a single session factory using both cfg.xml and programming?

Tags: xml, nhibernate, configuration, configuration-files

> Anyone knows how to configure connection string dynamically, while keeping the other parameters in the cfg.xml file?

Follows what should be contained in the cfg.xml file:

- dialect
- connection driver
- query substitutions

And what needs to be programmatically configured:

- connection string (using per-user and per-instance basis)

This means that the connection string is built dynamically, and the other parameters shall be static in the cfg.xml file (until they're changed manually in the XML).

> I was wondering whether this could do the trick?

[NHibernate using single configuration file to connect to multiple dbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471146/nhibernate-using-single-configuration-file-to-connect-to-multiple-dbs)

> Sequence

- The application is launched
- The application prompts the user to enter both his credentials and database instance
- The application verifies authentication against the database and either grant or refuse access based on the database response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can combine both. There is an example, reading the configuration first, then extending it with as many settings as needed:

```cs
ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(string connectionString) // from outer source
{
    // the Configuration, i.e.: native, NHibernate one
    var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

    var configFile = ... // a path to configuration ;

    // read that configuration file    
    var document = XDocument.Load(configFile);

    // pass it to the Configuration 
    using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
    {
        configuration.Configure(reader);
    }

    // so, the config file is applied, 
    // no its our dynamic turn
    configuration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", connectionString);
    configuration.SetProperty(....);

    // and now, we can ask for configuration to produce the factory
    var factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

    return factory;
}
```

Comment: +1 I have finally done quite alike. Thanks for your answer, this shall, I hope, help others along.

Comment: Great, great to see that. NHibernate is amazing tool ;)